# How can i use gyroscope in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried 'react-native-sensor-manager' and 'react-native-shake-event' and gyroscope in Expo. but i failed again and again. I don't know why. here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Gyroscope,
} from 'expo';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class GyroscopeSensor extends React.Component {
  state = {
    gyroscopeData: {},
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._toggle();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

  _toggle = () => {
    if (this._subscription) {
      this._unsubscribe();
    } else {
      this._subscribe();
    }
  }

  _slow = () => {
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(1000);
  }

  _fast = () => {
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(16);
  }

  _subscribe = () => {
    this._subscription = Gyroscope.addListener((result) => {
      this.setState({gyroscopeData: result});
    });
  }

  _unsubscribe = () => {
    this._subscription && this._subscription.remove();
    this._subscription = null;
  }

  render() {
    let { x, y, z } = this.state.gyroscopeData;

    return (
      <View >
        <Text>Gyroscope:</Text>
        <Text>x: {round(x)} y: {round(y)} z: {round(z)}</Text>

        <View >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggle} style={styles.button}>
            <Text>Toggle</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._slow} style={[styles.button, styles.middleButton]}>
            <Text>Slow</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._fast} >
            <Text>Fast</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function round(n) {
  if (!n) {
    return 0;
  }

  return Math.floor(n * 100) / 100;
}
```

View is rendered successfully but Gyroscope motion function is not working. how can i use Gyroscope in react-native??

Somebody help me..............................................

Answer (score 0):

You can't use those packages in plain expo because they require link.

You should read the expo documentation about what you can and can't do with it, to use those libs you'd need to expo `detach` to `expokit` so you could link native code.

Comment: I aleady tried gyroscope in expo but i failed... oh i forgot the detach! I will try!

Comment: That doesn't really say much to me, like what failed? The computer failed? the mousepad failed? Share error message when things failed, then people can give better answers.